# How do I save a user calculation into a variable?

Tags: python

So I have to make a program that does this:

> - Start with a welcome message
> - Display a menu with 3 basic shapes
> - Ask the user to input the dimensions of the 1st chosen shape and calculate its area
> - Return to the menu so the user can choose the 2nd shape
> - Ask the user to input the dimensions of the 2nd chosen shape and calculate its area
> - Decide whether the 1st shape is bigger, smaller or the same size as the second shape
> - Display the results
> - Once the first set of calculations is complete, ask the user if they would like to compare 2 more shapes. If yes, return them to the menu
>     to start again. If no, exit the program.

I've done most of the point but I don't know how I could save a user calculation to a variable so later they can be compared.

Here's the code:

```
while True:
    #Welcome message
    name = input("Hello what is your name ?")
    print("Hi",name,"welcome to my code.")

    #Menus for first figure

    #Menu for rectangle
    def rectangle():
        length = int(input("\nWhat is the length ?"))
        width = int(input("What is the width ?"))
        print("The area is",length * width,"\n")
        answer_1 = (length * width)
    #Menu for square
    def square():
        length = int(input("\nWhat is the length of the side ?"))
        print("The area of the square is", length * length,"\n")
        answer_2 = (length * length)
    #Menu for triangle
    def triangle():
        base = int(input("\nWhat is the length of the base ?"))
        height = int(input("What is height of the figure ?"))
        print("The area of the right-angled triangle is", base * height * 0.5,"\n")
        answer_3 = (base * height * 0.5)
    #Main Menu   
    def menu():
        print("What would you like to do ?\n")
        print("1: Rectangle")
        print("2: Square")
        print("3: Right-angled Triangle\n")
        choice = int(input("Enter choice:"))
        if choice == 1:
            rectangle()         
        elif choice == 2:
            square()
        elif choice == 3:
            triangle()
    menu()

    #Menus for second figure

    #menu for rectangle
    def rectanglee():
        length = int(input("\nWhat is the length ?"))
        width = int(input("What is the width ?"))
        print("The area is",length * width,"\n")
        answer_4 = (length * width)
    #Menu for square
    def squaree():
        length = int(input("\nWhat is the length of the side ?"))
        print("The area of the square is", length * length,"\n")
        answer_5 = (length * length)
    #menu for triangle
    def trianglee():
        base = int(input("\nWhat is the length of the base ?"))
        height = int(input("What is height of the figure ?"))
        print("The area of the right-angled triangle is", base * height * 0.5,"\n")
        answer_6 = (base * height * 0.5)
    #Main menu
    def menuu():
        print("What would you like to do ?")
        print("1: Rectangle")
        print("2: Square")
        print("3: Right-angled Triangle\n")
        choice = int(input("Enter choice:"))
        if choice == 1:
            rectanglee()
        elif choice == 2:
            squaree()
        elif choice == 3:
            trianglee()
    menuu()

    #Answer_1 and Answer_2
    answer_1 = int(input("What was the first answer ?"))
    answer_2 = int(input("What was the second answer ?"))

    #Comparing


    while True:
        answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
        if answer in ("y", "n"):
            break
        print("Invalid input.")
    if answer == "y":
        continue
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

The problem is that I have to ask the user to input the answers so they can be compared, I want to correct this so the program will know what to compare.

Comment: Your code is designed very bad. First there is no reason to define the functions inside the 'while' loop. secondly, why won't you just return the result from each shape function to menu and then compare each result? Do you have any background in programming?

Comment: I don't have a background in programming, I just started and I wanted to challenge myself, how would I go about fixing this then ?

Comment: Just google "python tutorial" and I'm sure you will find something suitable for you.

Comment: I know the basics I'm just trying to fix this, because if you run the code you'll see that it does what it's supposed to do you just have to enter the answers so they can be compared. I'm looking for a way for so the program can compare the results no matter what shapes have been chosen.

Comment: Patching a badly designed code to work isn't right, the fact that it does what it's supposed to do is a miracle for me because the code is designed very poorly. I can post a massive overhaul of your code so you learn from it

Comment: If you think it will help me then please do.